# Emacs theme not covering up the entire terminal window. The Ubuntu purple terminal background is showing on the edges

Tags: themes, term

At the bottom of the screen when emacs is open there is a strip of purple, meaning that emacs in terminal isnt maximizing to the full size that the terminal window allows and thus the background from the terminal is showing. I know this is nit-picky but my OCD is driving me crazy. Anyway to fix this?

I would post an image but I don't have enough stack karma points yet.

Comment: Comment a link to an image and I'll edit it in

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27758800/1219634) - Same question on SO

Comment: Yeah, someone on SO yelled at me for posting this question there and I didn't know how to delete it.  He was voting for removal?

Comment: @ADF I am **not** suggesting that this question should be closed as duplicate (and it also cannot be closed as duplicate as this is emacs.stackexchange and that is from stackoverflow); I simply put that link for extra reference. You are welcome to post such questions to emacs.SE :)

Answer (score 7):

The Emacs manual says you can set the option `frame-resize-pixelwise` to non-nil to allow frame sizes by pixel.  Normally the frame dimensions (not counting the menu bar, tool bar, etc) are integer multiples of `frame-char-height` in height and `frame-char-width` in width.  The manual notes that you need to set this variable to non-nil in your init file so that it interacts properly with you window manager.

In your `init.el` or `.emacs` file, add this:

```
(setq frame-resize-pixelwise t)
```

to enable pixel resizing rather than char height/width resizing.

> **User Option: frame-resize-pixelwise**
>
> If this option is nil, a frame’s size is usually rounded to a multiple of the current values of that frame’s frame-char-height and frame-char-width. If this is non-nil, no rounding occurs, hence frame sizes can increase/decrease by one pixel.
>
> Setting this causes the next resize operation to pass the corresponding size hints to the window manager. This means that this variable should be set only in a user’s initial file; applications should never bind it temporarily.
>
> The precise meaning of a value of nil for this option depends on the toolkit used. Dragging the frame border with the mouse is usually done character-wise. Calling set-frame-size (see below) with arguments that do not specify the frame size as an integer multiple of its character size, however, may: be ignored, cause a rounding (GTK+), or be accepted (Lucid, Motif, MS-Windows).
>
> With some window managers you may have to set this to non-nil in order to make a frame appear truly “maximized” or “fullscreen”.

Comment: This might not fully address the issue that OP is experiencing, but it helped me solve a problem that had been bothering me for a long time: having to tweak obscure settings in my window manager to make sure Emacs frames would properly maximize in KDE! So: Thank you and +1! :)